# PHP regex not matching right parenthisis

Tags: php

im using this regex to extract salaries from a file containing many different lines of text:

```
/(£|\€|GBP)\s*?(.)*?(pro-rata|\x28pro-rata\x29)/i
```

The test cases are like this:

> "Relevant Quantity Surveying construction drawings Salary: £36,999 (pro-rata) in accordance with standard construction terms ..."

It matches:

- £36,999 pro-rata
- €36,999 pro-rata
- GBP 36,999 pro-rata

But all matches of parenthesized 'pro-rata' are missing the right parenthtisis - i.e :

> £36,999 (pro-rata

any ideas what wrong with this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using

```
/(£|\€|GBP)\s*?(.)*?(pro-rata|\(pro-rata\))/i
```

and it works for me as expected.

Comment: `\x28` is a UTF-8 escape code for `(`, and `\x29` is the escape code for `)`.

Comment: it's definitely strange as the regex posted by the Op works fine for me, so it must be dependent on PHP version or OS or some other factor.

Comment: @ jdo - Yes your right  - this solution now works OK - i'm still stumped as to why it works now but not yesterday. My first attempt i used escaped literal parenthesis and only swapped to hex this morning - i think its as @Brandon Wamboldt said, a PCRE specific issue  very strange but many thanks

Answer (score 3):

This should be:

```
/(£|\€|GBP)\s*?(.)*?(\x28pro-rata\x29|pro-rata)/i
```

The problem is that you have `(.)*?` which will match any characters up to `pro-rata` including a `(` which means it matchings the first term in your regex (`pro-rata`).

Note: this behavior appears to differ for some PHP versions (possible based on the version of PCRE it was compiled with).

Comment: explanation was spot on but still doesnt work - tried jdo solution and it worked - very strange cos its exactly the same as my first solution last night???

Comment: The thing is: (.)* is getting you all the chars like space and ( in this scope. Then when the script is not getting ( it will get the second option without any parenthesis. In my script above I added the [0-9,] for it and a space, so it works how you wanted to.

Comment: @ailvenge  i really didn't want to use the 'all encompassing (.)* syntax but the content between the monetary char and the 'pro-rata' string could also include some random string like 'holidays', 'shifts', 'bonuses' etc ...

Answer (score 0):

I rewrited your pattern a bit:

```
\(£|\€|GBP)\s*?([0-9,]*)?\s*?(\x28pro-rata\x29|pro-rata)\i
```

For examples and why is that, take a look: http://regex101.com/r/mP4hX4